# Extracting and manipulating from logs with python

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm trying to parse a log which includes lines lines like this one:

```
2018-11-03 11:52:00,563 WARN  [ImapSSLServer-133] [ip=192.168.8.76;oip=123.123.123.123;via=192.168.8.76(nginx/1.7.1);ua=Zimbra/8.8.9_GA_3019;cid=1734;] security - cmd=Auth; account=username@example.com; protocol=imap; error=authentication failed for [username@example.com], invalid password;
```

I'm trying to understand how can I, from lines like this, extract the info of:
- oip
- account

The code that I've got so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

imap_failed=0
pop_failed=0
http_failed=0
smtp_failed=0
soap_failed=0

with open("/home/sebas/audit.log", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if "invalid" in line:
            if "protocol=imap" in line:
                imap_failed +=1
            if "protocol=pop" in line:
                pop_failed +=1
            if "protocol=http" in line:
                http_failed +=1
            if "oproto=smtp" in line:
                smtp_failed += 1
            if "protocol=soap" in line:
                soap_failed += 1
```

Thank you!

Comment: What would you like to extract? Just the piece `123.123.123.123`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use positive lookbehind (?<=...):

```
re.search(r"(?<=oip=)([\d\.]+)",line).group()
Out: '123.123.123.123'

re.search(r"(?<=account=)([^;]+)",line).group()
Out: 'username@example.com'
```